# "I'm flattered" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does "I'm flattered" mean in context.

For example; you find out someone is developing feelings for you and you say "I'm flattered.. I guess"

Comment: It means they're not that into you. It's a polite way of starting a sentence that can be summarized as "No."

Answer (score 6):

*"I'm flattered"*; in short, it means the same as *"I appreciate it"* or *"It's nice of you to say*"

> be/feel flattered ~Cambridge Dictionary ​
>
> *to feel very pleased and proud because someone has said good things about you or has made you feel important*

In the context you've provided, *"I'm flattered... I guess"* it most like means that this person feels both pleased and awkward because, apparently, they don't feel the same about the other person.

It's a *very* subtle way of rejecting someone ;)

Comment: Oh so when you say "I am flattered" , you don't feel the same about other person but you are pleased the fact that you gained attention. But when you say "I am flattered, I guess?" it means you awkwarded out but as original context means you dont feel in the same way. In either way, it means speaker doesn't feel in the same way and rejects that person's feelings. Am i right? :D

Comment: Not quite - "I am flattered" means that I'm pleased to hear something.  It's a positive message. There's nothing more to this. BUT, when I add "... I guess" afterwards, or maybe say it sarcastically, only then it adds some sense of weirdness to it. You can name it awkwardness, and from your context, conclude that it might be because the feelings aren't reciprocated.

Comment: But as overall, I'm flattered means/is used whenever someone doesn't feel the same with the other person, yet they pleased with the attention they got since it makes them feel more important. But speaker, politely refusing that person's feelings ?

Comment: @Drfub _"yet they pleased with the attention they got since it makes them feel more important"_ Not necessarily. It's just a set phrase at this point. It's meant to convey that they acknowledge your feelings. The alternative would be dismissing your feelings, which would make them seem rude. In other words, saying "I'm flattered" (a) protects your feelings (b) Makes them seem less rude for rebuffing you.

Comment: (Sorry for asking things constantly:)) So... in context of mine (the sentence in above) about  feelings, saying I am flattered technically means rejection. That, "speaker (who says I am flattered) is aware of other's feelings yet he/she doesn't want to respond them/will not respond them. I guess I got it right, right now?